# twig view checkbox value

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to view a checkbox in a form. But it is displayed N/A for 0 [image]and 1 for 1 [image].

How do I format the checkbox value to No for 0 and Yes for 1?

```
//twig
<div class="responsive-block">
  {{ UI.renderProperty('campuscrm.eventname.system_calendar.label'|trans, eventname.systemCalendar) }}
</div>

//FormType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // system calendar
    $builder->add(
        'system_calendar',
        CheckboxType::class,
        array(
            'label' => 'campuscrm.eventname.system_calendar.label',
            'required' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Data Transformer. ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html$t))

```
$builder->get('system_calendar')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($toString) {
            // transform the bool to a string
            return boolval($toString) ? "Yes" : "No";
        },
        function ($fromString) {
            // transform the string back to a bool
            return strval($fromString) == "Yes ? true : false;
        }
    ))
;
```

But I'm afraid that's not what you want to do. The checkbox component awaits a boolean value, you might pass something else. Could you confirm that you pass a boolean value? (You could do it with the transformer mentioned above or cast it before you pass it to the formbuilder)

Comment: For some reason your suggestion did not work. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around.

```
{{ UI.renderProperty('campuscrm.eventname.system_calendar.label'|trans, eventname.systemCalendar ? 'Yes' : 'No') }}
```